# Isotope.js not responsive like it is in Basic example

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I made a portfolio I'm pretty happy with at http://pressedweb.com/portfolio, but when I resize the window, it doesn't reorganize the container items like it does in this example: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/basic.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items are not being re-arranged on window resize because the size of the container does not change on window resize.

On the Isotope basic example, the width of the container is 'fluid,' and it responds to changes in window size.

Comment: Thanks David. Makes sense and if they're worried about Isotope not resizing, then they are probably making a responsive layout anyway and it will work so long as the Isotope container is resized appropriately when a media query is hit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#container_here..').isotope({ sortBy : 'random' });
});
```

Comment: This answer will be more useful to people if you give a brief statement of how/why it solves the stated problem.